# Libreoffice print hole between pages

Tags: printing, libreoffice

I have some kind of interesting issue with printing using Libreoffice. I have two pages of text. When i print it between those two pages I have some white space. Of course my footer is removed and header also. What else can generate this space ?

I also uploaded a small photo of this print - [CLICK](http://postimg.org/image/rtf7geqqv/)